# How to show modal of bootstrap 5 after select option and get value?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a form that contains a dropdown and some options:

```
<form action="#" class="modal-content">
    <select class="form-select" id="value" name="value">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="1">Number of Document</option>
        <option value="2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="2">Date</option>
        <option value="3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="3">Seller name</option>
        <option value="4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="4">Create date</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I also have a Bootstrap modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="valueModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="valueModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form action="#" class="modal-content">
            <input value="" name="option_id" type="hidden">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="valueModal">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Multi Forms -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to show the Bootstrap modal if the value "value" is selected.

I have tried doing this:

```
<script>
    $("#value").bind("change", function () {
        $('#valueModal').modal('show')(this.value === 'option_id');
    }).change();
</script>
```

The modal is opened by default so I know I'm targeting the modal but I would only like to display when the "value" option is selected.

And I have a hidden field in the modal of bootstrap 5

```
<input value="" name="option_id" type="hidden">
```

How do get the value after selecting the option value?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may help

```js
$("#value").bind("change", function () {
        if(this.value >=1)
        $('#valueModal').modal('show')
    }).change();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="modal-content">
    <select class="form-select" id="value" name="value">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="1">Number of Document</option>
        <option value="2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="2">Date</option>
        <option value="3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="3">Seller name</option>
        <option value="4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="4">Create date</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="valueModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="valueModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form action="#" class="modal-content">
            <input value="" name="option_id" type="hidden">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="valueModal">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Multi Forms -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyUE7.png   The value is empty

Comment: Do you want the popup should open on empty value also?

Comment: No, I want to get the value of the selected option change of title and input hidden field.